# Do published OSGI services need to have their packages exported?

Tags: osgi

Do the packages that contain OSGI services need to be exported in order to publish to the service registry? Or does publishing to the service registry get round the need to export the package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answers; 1st question = no, 2nd question = no, there's no "workaround"

The principle of "Design by contract" comes into play.  Basically we provide an interface for consumers to depend on and providers to implement - this decouples our consumer code for the implementation details of our implementors.  See http://www.osgi.org/blog/2011/08/package-as-contract.html for a good overview and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract.

Given the interface (the API we wish to use) and the implementation (the concrete implementation of the API interface) and the consumer (code wishing to use an implementation of the interface), with OSGi you have a number of options.

1. A bundle can provide both interface and implementation, but it must export the interface if this service is to be used outside of the bundle itself
2. Having a separate bundle for the interface (which it exports) and other bundle(s) for the implementation(s) - the implementing bundles must import the interface's package but need not reveal their own implementation.

The advantages of number 2 include allowing multiple providers (OSGi uses LDAP filters that can be used to specify metadata matching on the registered services' properties), and leveraging the dynamic binding nature of OSGi (i.e. you can change implementation provider at runtime).

One thing to bear in mind, is that the consumer and provider must use the same classes as defined by the package version and exporting bundle (in other words the bundle classloader that loads the API classes must be the same for both consumer and provider).

Answer (score 1):

The types of the service should be in exported packages. Services are typed and build upon the type sharing of the module layer. So you need to make sure that the provider of the service and the consumers of the service can all share the same type. So some bundle must export the package containing the type so that the provider and the consumers can import the package. This allows the framework to verify type safety of the service.